# XSD - unable to complete validation

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am trying to work on my XML / XSD file, but still the online validation page is wrong with me. Can you help me a little? Thank you.

Here is the whole code of my XSD file. The prolem is:

> s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_adresar' is
>   invalid. Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
>   line 5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="adresar">
        <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:element name="osoba" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="jmeno" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="prijmeni" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:attribute name="typ" type="at_type" use="required"/>
                        </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:element name="telefon" type="xsd:positiveInteger" minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:attribute name="typ" type="at_type" use="required"/>
                        </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:element name="web" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:attribute name="typ" type="at_type" use="required"/>
                        </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:element name="jiny" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:attribute name="jmeno" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                        </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:element name="adresa" type="adresa_type" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="poznamka" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="adresa_type">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ulice" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="cislopop" type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
            <xsd:element name="psc" type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
            <xsd:element name="mesto" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="at_type">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="osobni"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="pracovni"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="jiny"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just too many errors in your schema, I wouldn't even know where to start.

The one you're reporting is about `xsd:element` which you've placed directly in `xsd:complexType`. Add an intermediate `xsd:sequence`.

Next, you don't declare complex type within sequence. You don't place attributes within elements (you need a complex type with simple content and attribute for this).

I'd suggest that you start with [XSD Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/). It is much better than fighting syntax blindly.